# How to center the logo on a bootstrap navbar and have items around it, along with a search bar on the right?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5

I want to have my brand logo in the middle and some nav-items around it, with a search bar on the right, all vertically aligned.
[This is how my navbar looks.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gLOFu.png)

My code is this:

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-4bw+/aepP/YC94hEpVNVgiZdgIC5+VKNBQNGCHeKRQN+PtmoHDEXuppvnDJzQIu9" crossorigin="anonymous">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-HwwvtgBNo3bZJJLYd8oVXjrBZt8cqVSpeBNS5n7C8IVInixGAoxmnlMuBnhbgrkm" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>


    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg bg-body-tertiary border-bottom border-bottom-light bs-green sticky-top bg-body-tertiary" data-bs-theme="light">
    <div class="container-fluid">
            <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
                <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
            </button>

            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarSupportedContent">
                <div class="mx-auto order-0 justify-content-center">
                    <ul class="navbar-nav mb-2 mb-lg-0">
                        <li class="nav-item abs mt-1">
                            <a class="nav-link{%if active=='index'%} active{%endif%}" href="{{url_for('index')}}">Home</a>
                        </li>

                        <li class="nav-item abs mt-1">
                            <a class="nav-link {%if active=='about'%} active{%endif%}" href="{{url_for('about')}}">About us</a>
                        </li>

                        <li class="nav-item abs">
                            <img src="{{url_for('static', filename='logo.svg')}}" alt="" height="45" style="margin-left: 25px; margin-right: 25px;" />
                        </li>

                        <li class="nav-item abs mt-1">
                            <a class="nav-link {%if active=='blog'%} active{%endif%}" href="{{url_for('blog')}}">Articles</a>
                        </li>

                        <li class="nav-item abs mt-1">
                            <a class="nav-link {%if active=='ideas'%} active{%endif%}" href="{{url_for('ideas')}}">Ideas</a>
                        </li>

                        <li class="nav-item abs mt-1">
                            <a class="nav-link {%if active=='account'%} active{%endif%}" href="{{url_for('search')}}">Account (temp)</a>
                        </li>

                        <li class="nav-item me-auto mt-1">
                            <div class="collapse" id="search-bar">
                                <div class="input-group mb-3">
                                    <input type="text" class="form-control" aria-label="Text input with dropdown button">
                                    <button class="btn btn-outline-success dropdown-toggle" type="button" data-bs-toggle="dropdown" aria-expanded="false">Dropdown</button>
                                    <ul class="dropdown-menu dropdown-menu-end">
                                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Action</a></li>
                                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Another action</a></li>
                                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                                        <li><a class="dropdown-item" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <a href="#" class="nav-link">
                                <button type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#search-bar" aria-controls="search-bar" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle search bar">
                                    <i class="fa-solid fa-search"></i>
                                </button>
                            </a>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</nav>
```

I would like to have them all like this:

**SPACE SPACE link link logo link link SPACE search**

Comment: Could you add your css as well? Also I think you should use a 3 column structure for this

Comment: add margin or padding to logo or links :)

Comment: @Webdeveloper_Jelle I don't have any extra css besides bootstrap

Comment: I managed to do something, but it still won't work on bigger devices, I just used d-flex on the search box and used justify content end for it to align, but it doesnt really work that great

Comment: Your snippet doesn't show anything, can you fix that?

Comment: @Webdeveloper_Jelle still looks wonky without fa and the logos